# How do I disable these keyboard shortcuts in a NSTextView?

Tags: macos, cocoa, keyboard-shortcuts, nstextview

I have an NSTextView which I'm kind of using as a full-screen canvas for letters.

The following key combinations do things that I don't want to do (e.g. hide my window, lock up the computer).

How can I disable them to stop them being invoked?

- Command-a
- Command-h
- Command-j
- Command-p
- Command-u

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure you understand [the path of key events](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH3-SW10) and [user interface validation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UIValidation/Articles/implementingValidation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006268-SW1).

I think the best way to disable the actions you mention is by subclassing NSTextView and disabling their associated menu items by declaring your text view as conforming to `NSUserInterfaceValidations` and writing the validation method:

```
- (BOOL)validateUserInterfaceItem:(id<NSValidatedUserInterfaceItem>)anItem {

    SEL action = [anItem action];
    if (@selector(selectAll:) == action ||                    // command-a
        @selector(centerSelectionInVisibleArea:) == action || // command-j
        @selector(print:) == action ||                        // command-p
        @selector(underline:) == action) {                    // command-u

        return NO;
    }
    else return [super validateUserInterfaceItem:anItem];
}
```

However that doesn't prevent the user from hiding the app via Command+H. To disable that key combo you can either remove its key equivalent in the MainMenu XIB, or you can subclass NSApplication and override `hide:`

Answer (score 0):

Override the NSEvents for these key combinations to do nothing instead of what they will normally be doing.